# Concatenate 2 columns within a single .txt file and separate by ":" using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a ~40 million line tab delimited .txt file with the following columns:

```
1   rs58108123  10583
1   rs58108140  10611
1   rs58123442  13302
...
```

I need to combine columns 1 and 3 into a single column in the column 1 position. This is the desired output:

```
1:10583 rs58108123
1:10611 rs58108140
1:13302 rs58123442
...
```

From what I understand, this can be accomplished using the awk command. I'm very new to the command line, so I've not been able to figure out the specifications required to accomplish this task. If you could please provide an explanation to accompany any possible solutions, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Can you post the data from the linked images directly in your post?

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
awk '{print $1":"$3"\t"$2}' < infile.txt
```

This will print Column $1:Column $3 followed by a tab character "\t" and then Column $2.

You can save the output to a file by adding `> outfile.txt` at the end of the command.

You can find some more examples of simple awk syntax here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/

Comment: Don't put screenshotted text in your question next time, just put the text directly, that's why you got the downvotes.  Also mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101124/official-reference-for-dont-leave-thank-you-comments